# React js set state in functional component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a functional login component. When i have commented the onChange i get the below error in the browser

```
index.js:1 Warning: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.
```

> And if i uncomment onChange and i try to username field i get the
> below error Login.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'inputChangedHandler' of undefined
> at onChange (Login.js:20)

How to solve it?
import React, { useState, props } from 'react';

```
const Login = (prop) => {

    const [username] = useState('Mr x');


    const inputChangedHandler = (event) => {
        const updatedKeyword = event.target.value;
        // May be call for search result
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <div className="container">

                User Name: <input type="text" name="username" value={username}
                  //  onChange={(event) => this.inputChangedHandler(event)}
                     />

                    Password: <input type="password" name="password" />
                <button className="btn btn-success"  >Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}


export default Login;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `this` from `this.inputChangedHandler(event)`

And to actually change the value you need to add a setter to your `useState` like this `const [username,setUsername] = useState('Rahul Raj');`

And then use it like this `onChange={(event) => setUsername(event.target.value)}`

Comment: then my username fields become 'read-only'

Comment: See the update, let me know if it solves your issue.

Comment: it works .Thanks can u let me know what is setUsername

Comment: Each `useState` returns 2 values 1) is the current value `username` in your case and a setter function `setUsername` in your case which when called updates the value of `username` to the value passed in (just note that both `username` and `setUsername` are generic names and can be called anything), let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: For that you need to setup another `useState` const like this `const [password,setPassword] = useState("");` and use it in the password input just like you did in the username. hope this answers your question.

Comment: Yes solved it.Thanks for explaining the concept.